# Obtain data outside the query in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, callback

I'm doing a shopping cart and I have to obtain the price of the products in order to multiply by the quantity but I have the problem of the asynchrony and I can't get the price in each iteration of the loop.

```js
router.get('/cartlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('cart');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){


  var totalPrice = 0;
     for(var i in docs)
     {
      var name = docs[i].productname;
      var amount = docs[i].amount;

      var products = db.get('products');



      var idPrice = 0;
      getPrice(products, name, function(data)
      {
       idPrice = data;
      });



      console.log(idPrice);
     }
        
        totalPrice += idPrice * amount;

  console.log(totalPrice);

        res.render('cartlist', {
            "cartlist" : docs
        });
    });
});
```

And the callback:

```js
function getPrice(collection, name, callback)
{
 collection.findOne({"productname" : name}, {_id:0, price:1}, function(err, objs)
 {
  if(objs != null)
   {
    callback(objs.price);
   }
 });
}
```

When I display the value of the totalPrice is 0. How can I do this? I need to obtain the price in order to do totalprice += amount * price in the loop. Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show some sample documents from the `cart` and `products` collections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your cart and product collections have the following bare minimum schema:

**Cart**

```
- productname (reference to product collection on productname field)
- amount
```

**Product**

```
- productname
- price
```

Then it's much easier and efficient to use the aggregation framework and run a pipeline that takes the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** operator to perform a left outer join to the `products` collection in the same database to filter in documents from the "joined" collection for processing and then calculate the total price within a **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline using the **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** and **[`$multiply`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/#exp._S_multiply)** operators.

The following example shows how you can go about this

```
router.get('/cartlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('cart');
    collection.aggregate([
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "products",
                "foreignField": "productname",
                "localField": "productname",
                "as": "productList"
            }
        },
        { "$unwind": "$productList" },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": null,
                "totalPrice": {
                    "$sum": {
                        "$multiply": [
                            "$productList.price",
                            "$amount"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "cartlist": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
            }
        }

    ], function(err, result){
        console.log(result);
        console.log(result[0]);
        console.log(result[0].totalPrice);
        res.render("cartlist", result);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Now I have to try to encode stuff like 3x2 in products. Do you have any idea to do it in this left outer join?

Comment: I could if I have an example product document. Would you mind sharing some sample documents by editing your question and include them?

Comment: The product document is similar like yours but with one or two field more with additional info: like if it is a drink or a meal. I have to try to make a 20% of discount if we have a menu in the cart (meal, drink and dessert)